# What are these "O-Power" things?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

What are O-Powers? How many of them are there? And what do they do? There's a small explanation on the screen, but there's also a meter at the bottom. What does that do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O-Powers can be thought of as skills used by the trainer instead of his/her Pokémon.

Unlike a Pokémon's PP, the trainer's energy restores over time. The amount of energy available to use an O-Power is represented by the number of orbs in the bottom bar.

O-Powers can level up when used often. Higher levels mean greater effect, but also greater costs to use.

It is currently unknown how many O-Powers there are in total, but here are the ones I've found so far:

- **3 minute powers<sup>1</sup>**

  - *Bargain Power*: Poké Marts begin a bargain sale in which everything is **x**% off.**<sup>a</sup>**
  - *Prize Money Power*: Increases the prize money from battles.
  - *Exp. Point Power*: Increases the Exp. Points from battles.
  - *Capture Power*: Increases the chance to catch Pokémon.
  - *Encounter Power*: Increases the chance of encountering wild Pokémon.**<sup>b</sup>**
  - *Stealth Power*: Decreases he chance of encountering wild Pokémon.**<sup>b</sup>**
  - *Befriending Power*: Helps Pokémon grow friendly faster.
- **Instant powers**

  - *HP Restoring Power*: Restores the HP of the lead Pokémon.
  - *PP Restoring Power*: Restores the PP of the lead Pokémon.
- **Battle powers<sup>2</sup>**

  - *Attack Power*
  - *Defense Power*
  - *Sp. Atk Power*
  - *Sp. Def Power*
  - *Speed Power*
  - *Critical Power*: Raises the critical hit ratio of the lead Pokémon during battle.

New powers are given to you by a man calling himself `[...] Mr. Bonding, the expert on O-Powers.` He is usually found in hotels or Poké Centers.

---

<sup>1</sup>: Including time spent in combat
<sup>2</sup>: Only active for the next battle. If more than one are used at once, the effects will be added progressively each turn, e.g: the Pokémon receives an Attack boost during round 1, then a Defense boost during round 2 and so on.

<sup>a</sup>: **x**% is 10% for level 1.
<sup>b</sup>: Cannot be given to others.

Comment: What does "Cannot be given to others" mean? What can be given to others?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha "Giving" an O-Power to someone else is like buffing him/her. Basically, 2 players buffing each other can profit more, than if they used their O-Power on themselves.

Comment: 2 players? I can play with two players? :O How? (Or are you talking about my Friends list?)

Comment: @MadaraUchiha When you encounter another player over Streetpass, or when you're online, you can see a list of "Passersby". There is also a list of "Acquaintances" and "Friends". You can buff anyone that appears in those lists.

Comment: O-Power energy regenerates faster if you have taken steps during the day and it increases up to 4x regeneration rate.

Comment: You can save O-power energy by using it on yourself, then your friends tap on you followed by "Receive O-power". Taking it in turns to be generously selfish will increase the total time you all can be buffed. However this method will slow your O-power leveling so it is best reserved for level 3 powers.

Answer (score 1):

O-Powers are temporary buffs that you can give to yourself or other players. They have different effects ranging from increased chance for capture to HP restoration. Each O-Power use costs a certain amount of energy, which regenerates over time. Using O-Powers on other people costs less energy than using it on yourself, meaning it's much more efficient to buff other people.